Metal Oxide Varistor
Asking for recommendations on selecting a correct Metal Oxide Varistor (varistor) size for a home sprinkler system (surge-protector circuit I am building).
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to this; I have a little experience with electric circuits.
Circuit voltage is 26 VDC.  I have 24 sprinkler zones (in 4 different areas throughout the yard). Each zone controls a solenoid powered by 26 VDC, 2 wires to each solenoid (26 VDC and a return (common)) from the sprinkler controller.  I plan on building a surge protector for each zone, a metal box with place for 24 fuse holders. The surge protector box will be placed between the controller and the solenoid; and will be located in the garage (close to the sprinkler controller). Each zone will have a fuse (2 AMP, 6mm x 30mm fuse). I plan on placing a varistor between the 26 VDC and the return (common), and then between the 26 VDC and ground, and from the return (common) to the ground (for each zone).
I live in Florida and for some reason have lost 3 sprinkler controllers to lightening (last 2 years). My surge protector design is to (also) try to determine which zone maybe causing the problem. I need to do something...
I need help selecting an appropriate Metal Oxide Varistor (varistor) device (size and type).
I hope this text was not too long and provided enough information.  Thank you (all) for your help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
